# how to do 301 redirects from old site to new

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, apache2

I have a website which is on Wordpress `www.old.example.com` and on its own IP/Server `10.1.1.1`

It has various pages which are ranked on google which I'd like to preserve.

I have a new website `www.new.example.com` which is configured using APACHE2 Vhosts and is also on its own IP/Server `10.2.2.2`

How do I do 301 redirects? Do I do the 301 redirects in Wordpress on `www.old.example.com` or do I change its IP address to point to the new server and then do the redirects in the [www.new.example.com](http://www.new.example.com) `.conf` file?

Answer (score 1):

Either way works fine. First one is easier, you can just add the redirects.

Using the second option requires you to set up virtual hosts on the new server.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the redirect option because you can redirect the whole site or a specific section.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.old.example.com
    .
    .
    .
    Redirect permanent / http://www.new.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Description:

```
Redirect [status] [URL-path] URL
```

- **status**: you can move: permanetn, temp, seeother, gone the web page
- **URL-path**: Set URI
- **URL**: New domain/New web

Doc: [more information](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent)